# How long will it take to heal a hairline fracture of rib?

Tags: disease, bone-fractures, x-rays

My Grand father who is 96 years old got hairline fracture of the rib. How long it will take to heal? His doctor said you dont need to come back for xray.

Comment: Have you googled something? Like "How long does it take to heal a line fracture of the rib?"

Comment: It say 6 to 8 weeks. Since he is very old  it migjt take little longer than that.

Comment: Right, I think that too. I'd suggest to consult a healthcare provider to know for sure the situation.

Comment: Yes..Thanks for replying